# .htaccess redirect strip old system content from end of URL

Tags: htaccess, redirects, regex

Looking to redirect all URLs which look similar to this:

```
https://www.example.com/discussion/topix/random-page-title.133760/posts/1255466/rate?rating=13&_Token=78139%2C1464617730%2Ca42dfb1db7e54b51db1879075650aaf4a3c3323a
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/discussion/topix/random-page-title.133760/
```

Basically removing the following from the URL:

```
posts/1255466/rate?rating=13&_Token=78139%2C1464617730%2Ca42dfb1db7e54b51db1879075650aaf4a3c3323a
```

They are parts of an old system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/discussion/topix/(.*)/posts/.*$ /discussion/topix/$1/
```

`(.*)` is a capturing group which matches anything preceding ‘posts’.
`$1` outputs the capturing group as the destination for the redirect.

Comment: Thats perfect thank you,  although it leaves the part of the URL starting /rate?
Is there anyway of stripping that last part of the URL too ?

Comment: Actually,  Unfortunately that conflicts with another part of the site which has a URL such as https://www.example.com/discussion/posts/1059959/ 

which acts differently.  Is there a way of narrowing it down so it only checks for /posts/ after the /topix/ directory

Comment: @Randomer See edit, it now only matches if the path starts with /discussion/topix/

Comment: Perfect thank you very much Grgarside I have marked the answer as correct :)

Comment: There's no need to escape the slashes in the source URL regex. However, this won't remove the query string on the original request (you'll be left with `?rating=13.....` appended to the end of the target URL). To remove the query string "cleanly" you'd need to use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive.

Comment: Thank you MrWhite,  I did indeed leave that at the end.   I accepted it as the destination topics in question had its canonical, so providing the users were redirected back to the page rather than a 404,  I was happy with the outcome.   I will however try a RewriteRule to clean it up :)